# Attempting to send a json string via WebSockets to Javascript and getting a Syntax Error

Tags: php, javascript, json, websocket

This is the json object:

```
{"Packet":{"Response":"Handshake","Code":"lmhn","UID":"4e1d137caaed7"}}
```

For some reason I am getting a syntax error declaring an illegal token. I don't see it, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that's valid JSON, and [this validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) agrees.

I think you need to show us more of what you're doing and tell us exactly what's giving the syntax error.

Comment: Had the data being sent wrapped in null ascii characters through the socket. Parsed it out before evaluating JSON. All is well.